# Merge multiple ArcMap .lyr files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, layers, symbology

I have several .lyr files (from an external organisation) which have different features specific to the shapefile the layer file was made for. I have combined the shapefiles and would now like to combine the layer files so that I have all the styles for all the features in the combined shapefile. I am struggling to find a away to do this, so I was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible?

I've found that by grouping layers, you can export a grouped layer, but that is not ideal, but might have to be my solution.

Comment: +1 interesting problem. I don't know if this is possible since layer files are associated with a particular shapefile. If you merged the shapefiles together, I don't think the layer files would apply the symbology based on the attributes.

Comment: The layer files do still apply symbology as the attributes haven't changed, but those features that are have been added may not have symbology if they're not in the layer file, although as I've said, using group layers and adding the layer files from each of the merged shapefiles, and then pointing the layer files at the new, combined shapefile, seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The layers should still work with the merged shapefile if you set that as the source (do check that 'All other values' is not ticked in the symbology).

1. Change the source for each layer file to the new merged shapefile (Properties>Source>Set Data Source)
2. Add all the layer files to an mxd(now all referencing the same source - the merged shapefile).
3. Group the layers and save the group as a new layer file.

This doesn't merge the layer files, but at least you are only referencing the one shapefile.